# MongoDB: Remove duplicate records from Projection

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, pymongo, projection

How can I remove duplicate records from mongoDB projection ? 
Lets say I have My mongo documents in following form -

```
{"_id":"55555454", "From":"Bob", "To":"Alice", "subject":"Hi", "date":"04102011"} 
{"_id":"55555455", "From":"Bob", "To":"Dave", "subject":"Hello", "date":"04102014"}
{"_id":"55555456", "From":"Bob", "To":"Alice", "subject":"Bye", "date":"04112013"}
```

When I do a simple projection 
`db.col.find({}, {"From":1, "To":1, "_id"=0})`

which will obviously give me all three records like this.

> {"From":"Bob", "To":"Alice"} {"From":"Bob","To":"Dave"} {"From":"Bob",
>   "To":"Alice"}

However What I want is only two records, this way -

```
{"From":"Bob", "To":"Alice"} {"From":"Bob","To":"Dave"}
```

As My application is in python currently (using pymongo), what I am doing is that I am removing duplicate in the application from the list of records using

```
result = [dict(tupleized) for tupleized in set(tuple(item.items()) for item in l)]
```

Is there any DB method which I can apply to the projection and gives me only two records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a reduction and eliminate duplicate documents using just `find` with MongoDB and a projection.

The `find` commands won't work as you need remember that it's returning a cursor to the client and as such, can't reduce the results to only those documents that are unique without a secondary pass.

Using this as test data (removed the `_id`):

```
> db.test.find()
{ "From" : "Bob", "To" : "Alice", "subject" : "Hi", "date" : "04102011" }
{ "From" : "Bob", "To" : "Dave", "subject" : "Hello", "date" : "04102014" }
{ "From" : "Bob", "To" : "Alice", "subject" : "Bye", "date" : "04112013" }
{ "From" : "Bob", "To" : "Alice", "subject" : "Hi", "date" : "04102011" }
{ "From" : "Bob", "To" : "Dave", "subject" : "Hello", "date" : "04102014" }
{ "From" : "Bob", "To" : "Alice", "subject" : "Bye", "date" : "04112013" }
{ "From" : "Bob", "To" : "Dave", "subject" : "Hello", "date" : "04102014" }
{ "From" : "Bob", "To" : "Alice", "subject" : "Bye", "date" : "04112013" }
{ "From" : "George", "To" : "Carl", "subject" : "Bye", "date" : "04112013" }
{ "From" : "David", "To" : "Carl", "subject" : "Bye", "date" : "04112013" }
```

You could use aggregation:

```
> db.test.aggregate({ $group: { _id: { "From": "$From", "To": "$To" }}})
```

Results:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                    "From" : "David",
                    "To" : "Carl"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                    "From" : "George",
                    "To" : "Carl"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                    "From" : "Bob",
                    "To" : "Dave"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                    "From" : "Bob",
                    "To" : "Alice"
            }
        }
],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The [Python](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html) code should look very similar to the aggregation pipeline suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Projection only defines which fields you want to appear in the result. It is much like the statement starting with:

```sql
SELECT From, To
```

as opposed to the basic form of

```sql
SELECT *
```

So what you actually wanted to do was the equivalent of this:

```javascript
db.collection.find(
    { "From": "Bob", "To": "Alice" },
    { "From": 1, "To": 1 }
)
```

Which actually selects the records that you want and is much the same form as:

```sql
SELECT From, To
FROM collection
WHERE
   From = "Bob"
   AND To = "Alice"
```

Should that actually somehow produce "duplicate" results the you can remove this with use of aggregate:

```javascript
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$match": {
       "From": "Bob", "To": "Alice"
   }}
   { "$group": {
       "_id": { 
           "From": "$From", "To": "$To"
       }
   }}       
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer. I understand what projection is But I want more after this - which is Remove duplicate items from that projected view !

Comment: @sanj Which part of that you did not actually select the items in your query do you not understand? That is also in the answer.

Comment: @sanj Cleanly provided something that actually provides an answer if you have duplicates despite the interruptions.